# The usage of 'in which'

Tags: word-usage

> 'There isn’t a day that goes by in which I’m not trying to solve a problem.'

Question: How do you use 'in which' here?
Are there any similar examples for the usage of 'in which'?

Comment: How about, *The car in which she was travelling*. *The country in which I was born*. *The principles in which I believe* etc.

Comment: The forum in which you are asking this question may severely reprimand you. You must clearly mention the context in which you intend to use our services.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about time we usually use (when) and (when) = in/on/ at which

- Friday is the day on which (when) we get up late.
- The place in which (where) I met her is far from here.

And talking about the place too
Where = in/at/on/to which

In which is not necessary. 
Like '' In which'' in this context

> The way in which you do that,however,can be very difficult from situation to situation
>
> The way you do that,however,can be very difficult from situation to situation.